# Converting input to lowercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

not a coder at all, making a little project. Does anyone know how I can make my input here case insensitive? I have tried to add a line similar to

```
name = name.map(function(x){ return x.toLowerCase() })
```

but this didn't work and with no coding background I'm finding it hard to troubleshoot what is going wrong.

Thank you :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="name" type="text">
  <input id="check" type="button" value="Check">

  <p id="para"></p>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var names = ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5"];
      names = names.map(function(x) {
        return x.toLowerCase()
      })

      $('#check').click(function() {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        if (jQuery.inArray(name, names) != '-1') {
          document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "We cover this postcode";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "We do not cover this postcode ";
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have case insensitivity you need to have both the values in same case, whereas you're just changing value of `names` to lowerCase but not the value of `name` toLowerCase.

So just change both the values to same case and than match

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="name" type="text">
  <input id="check" type="button" value="Check">

  <p id="para"></p>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var names = ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5"];
      names = names.map(function(x) {
        return x.toLowerCase()
      })

      $('#check').click(function() {
        var name = $('#name').val().toLowerCase();  // notice to lowercase here
        if (jQuery.inArray(name, names) != '-1') {
          document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "We cover this postcode";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "We do not cover this postcode ";
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the text in variable, then pass it with [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) function.

```
var str = "Hello World!";
var res = str.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Please use proper formatting for showing code. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the input to lowercase using `toLowerCase()` and then check if is present in `array` or not . i.e :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 var names = ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5"];
  names = names.map(function(x) {
    var a= x.toLowerCase()
 console.log(a);

  $('#check').click(function() {
    var name = $('#name').val().toLowerCase();
    if (jQuery.inArray(name, a) != '-1') {
      document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "We cover this postcode";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "We do not cover this  postcode ";
    }
  });
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" type="text">
<input id="check" type="button" value="Check">

<p id="para"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

var strring = "Convert String to Lower";

var result = str.toLowerCase();

Comment: You already have posted this solution... https://stackoverflow.com/a/57450608/2227743